# Inserção dos dados no banco de dados em C#

Tags: c#

Minha classe `Cliente`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Objetos_de_Transferencia
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int id_cli { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int telefone { get; set; }
        public int telemovel { get; set; }
        public string morada { get; set; }
        public string sexo { get; set; }
        public DateTime data_nasc { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Minha classe `ClienteDAO`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Objetos_de_Transferencia;

namespace AcessoBancoDados
{
    public class ClienteDAO
    {

        public ConnectionBD connectionBD = new ConnectionBD();
        public SqlCommand cmd = null;
        public SqlDataReader dr = null;

        SqlConnection con = null;

        Cliente cliente = null;

        //// metodo para inserir um novo cliente
        public void gravar(Cliente cliente) {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Cliente2(nome, telefone, telemovel, morada, sexo, data_nasc, email)values(@nome, @telefone, @telemovel, @morada, @sexo, @data_nasc, @email)", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cliente.nome);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", cliente.telefone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telemovel", cliente.telemovel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@morada", cliente.morada);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", cliente.sexo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nasc", cliente.data_nasc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", cliente.email);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                con.Close();
            }


        }

        //// metodo para atualizar os dados
        public void atualizar(Cliente cliente) {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("update Cliente2 set nome = @nome, telefone = @telefone, telemovel = @telemovel, morada = @morada, sexo = @sexo, data_nasc = @data_nasc, email = @email where id_cli = @id_cli", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_cli", cliente.id_cli);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cliente.nome);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", cliente.telefone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telemovel", cliente.telemovel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@morada", cliente.morada);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", cliente.sexo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nasc", cliente.data_nasc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", cliente.email);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //// metodo para excluir um cliente
        public void ecluir(int codigo) {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Cliente2 where id_cli = @id_cli", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_cli", codigo);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //// metodo para obter um cliente pelo id
        public Cliente pesquizarPorCodigo(int codigo) {



            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Cliente2 where id_cli = @id_cli", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_cli", codigo);

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                /// vai ter que varrer tudo e procurar o que o usuario digitou
                while (dr.Read()) {

                    cliente = new Cliente();  ///// assim consigo regatar tudo que esta dentro dessa classe Cliente

                    cliente.id_cli      = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.nome        = Convert.ToString(dr["nome"]);
                    cliente.telefone    = Convert.ToInt32(dr["telefone"]);
                    cliente.telemovel   = Convert.ToInt32(dr["telemovel"]);
                    cliente.morada      = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.sexo        = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.data_nasc   = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.email       = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);
                }

                return cliente;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //// metodo para listar todos os clientes cadastrados
        public List<Cliente> listar() {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Cliente2", con);

                //////  muda um pouco
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();

                while(dr.Read()){

                    cliente.id_cli = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.nome = Convert.ToString(dr["nome"]);
                    cliente.telefone = Convert.ToInt32(dr["telefone"]);
                    cliente.telemovel = Convert.ToInt32(dr["telemovel"]);
                    cliente.morada = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.sexo = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.data_nasc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["id_cli"]);
                    cliente.email = Convert.ToString(dr["id_cli"]);

                    lista.Add(cliente);
                }

                return lista;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally {

                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ação no botão cadastrar no code Behind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AcessoBancoDados;
using Objetos_de_Transferencia;

namespace Apresentacao
{
    public partial class fmCliente : Form
    {
        Cliente cliente = null;
        ClienteDAO clienteDAO = null;

        public fmCliente()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tbnCadastrarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cliente = new Cliente();

                cliente.nome        = tbNome.Text;
                cliente.telefone    = Convert.ToInt32(tbTelefone.Text);
                cliente.telemovel   = Convert.ToInt32(tbTelemovel.Text);
                cliente.morada      = tbMorada.Text;
                cliente.sexo        = tbSexo.Text;
                cliente.data_nasc   = dtpData_Nasc.Value;
                cliente.email       = tbEmail.Text;

                clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();

                clienteDAO.gravar(cliente);  //// acessei a minha classa ClienteDAO

                //// DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                MessageBox.Show("Cliente "+cliente.nome+" cadastrado com sucesso!!!!!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhes" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre aqui:

```cs
throw new Exception("Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhes" + ex.Message);
```

Esta é a mensagem de erro:

```
Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhesA referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto
```

O erro dá-se aqui na chamada do método gravar:

```cs
private void tbnCadastrarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cliente = new Cliente();

            cliente.nome        = tbNome.Text;
            cliente.telefone    = Convert.ToInt32(tbTelefone.Text);
            cliente.telemovel   = Convert.ToInt32(tbTelemovel.Text);
            cliente.morada      = tbMorada.Text;
            cliente.sexo        = tbSexo.Text;
            cliente.data_nasc   = dtpData_Nasc.Value;
            cliente.email       = tbEmail.Text;

            clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();

            clienteDAO.gravar(cliente);  //// acessei a minha classa ClienteDAO

            //// DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            MessageBox.Show("Cliente "+cliente.nome+" cadastrado com sucesso!!!!!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhes" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using AcessoBancoDados.Properties;   //// para poder pegar a minha string de conexao

namespace AcessoBancoDados
{
    public class ConnectionBD
    {
        //criar a minha conexao e rtorna a minha string de conexao
        public SqlConnection criarConexao()
        {

            return new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.connectionString);  //pegando a minha string de conexao com a minha classe setting para trazer a string Conexao
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: quando tento inserir um novo cliente, ele me retorna o seguinte erro: Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhesA referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.

Comment: se puder ajudar, agradeço imenso

Comment: O erro da-se nessa parte:

Comment: throw new Exception("Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhes" + ex.Message);

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: Esse erro: Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhesA referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto

Comment: Sim. Alguma coisa está nula. Ele devolve uma *Stack Trace*?

Comment: Coloque o código desse métdo "connectionBD.criarConexao()" na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Debugando em que momento estoura o erro. Você colocou o catch, mas o erro estourou dentro do try. Se for no momnto em que chama o gravar(), debugando o gravar, em que momento ele dá o erro ou em outro método. Podes postar isso?

Comment: Erro dentro do catch

Comment: E diz o seguinte:

Comment: Erro ao efetuar o cadastro:.... detalhesA referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto

Comment: Quando ele entra no `gravar` e cria uma instância está retornando `con` diferente de nulo?

Comment: @AntonioGoncalves, gostaria de apontar dois anti-pattern no seu codigo, 1 - você está fazer o re-throw da maneira errada `new Exception(ex.Message)`, você está descatando toda informação sobre o erro antes dele ser tratado, faça `new Exception("Sua Mensagem de Erro", ex)`, o segundo ponto é não usar o `using` para objetos que implementam o IDisposable, no caso o `SqlConnection` e `SqlCommand`. Por fim, aconselho que implemente `UnitOfWork Pattern` para evitar ficar criando uma conexão a cada chamada.

Answer (score 1):

Confira se a string de conexão chega corretamente pelo classe `Setting`. Se estiver ok, o problema é que na sua classe `ClienteDAO` você tem duas instâncias do `SqlConnection`:

```cs
public class ClienteDAO
    {

        public ConnectionBD connectionBD = new ConnectionBD();
        public SqlCommand cmd = null;
        public SqlDataReader dr = null;

        SqlConnection con = null; // <--- Uma instância

        Cliente cliente = null;

        //// metodo para inserir um novo cliente
        public void gravar(Cliente cliente) {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao(); // <--- Outra instância

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Cliente2(nome, telefone, telemovel, morada, sexo, data_nasc, email)values(@nome, @telefone, @telemovel, @morada, @sexo, @data_nasc, @email)", con);
                //etc
```

Aconselho você deixar a instanciação da conexão dentro de cada método que será responsável por alguma conexão com o banco de dados.

Sendo assim, ficaria dessa forma:

```cs
public class ClienteDAO
    {

        public ConnectionBD connectionBD = new ConnectionBD();
        public SqlCommand cmd = null;
        public SqlDataReader dr = null;

        Cliente cliente = null;

        //// metodo para inserir um novo cliente
        public void gravar(Cliente cliente) {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = connectionBD.criarConexao();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Cliente2(nome, telefone, telemovel, morada, sexo, data_nasc, email)values(@nome, @telefone, @telemovel, @morada, @sexo, @data_nasc, @email)", con);
                //etc
```

Comment: Sinceramente nao vi alteracao no seu codigo

Comment: Você tem de fazer dois testes...uma com a alteração da duplicidade que eu citei e conferir a classe Settings. Tem como colocar o código da classe Settings? quero ver como você faz pra pegar esse Settings.Default.connectionString

Comment: Bem, obrigado pela vossa ajuda, ate que enfim ja consegui resolver o problema, o problema mesmo estava na abertura da conexao, era so colocar o con.Close() antes de fazer a consulta, obrigado na mesma

Answer (score 0):

Antônio, aconselho usar em suas rotinas o método

```
using (sqlconnection con = New connectionDb.abreConexao());
{
 Rotina de interação com o banco aqui.
}
```